# Set Accessor is getting hit three times for WPF DatePicker when month is changed

Tags: wpf, xaml, datepicker

I've two DatePickers(Startdate and Enddate) in my view which are bound to Two different properties of type DateTime? in ViewModel. I've a validation in my view model which always check whether Startdate is less than End date or not.

My View Code goes like this:

```
<DatePicker Style="{StaticResource DatePickerStyle}" Focusable="False"
                                            SelectedDate="{Binding EViewModel.StartDate}"
                                            x:Name="EStartDate"/>

<DatePicker Style="{StaticResource DatePickerStyle}" Focusable="False"
                                                SelectedDate="{Binding EViewModel.EndDate}"
                                                x:Name="EEndDate"/>
```

My validator code goes like this:

```
public static string StartandEndDateFieldValidator(object value, DateTime? startDate, DateTime? endDate)
        {

            string errorMsg = null;
            if (value != null)
            {
                if (startDate > endDate)
                {
                    errorMsg = DateErrorMessage;
                    MessageBox.Show(errorMsg);

                }

            }
            return errorMsg;
        }
```

My problem is, when I choose start date as today and open the drop down of end date and select previous month using month navigator button(arrow at the left side of month on the top of dropdown), 1st of previous month is getting selected as default and set accesor is getting called 3 times and hence validation pop up is coming thrice. I've to click on Ok for 3 times in this case. I couldn't understand why is this happening.

Please help me out to get this thing fixed.

Comment: This is not a reproducible example. Tried the same thing you did it firing setter for each property only when you select date. Can you provide more information on this? Are you setting the StartDate and EndDate somewhere else?

Comment: No, I'm actually setting the values directly to client Model and calling this validator from clientModel everthing I set the date, This validator is not getting called because set itself is not getting hit.